# DoCmd.RunCommand acCmdSaveRecord resets sub

Tags: ms-access

I have a form that is quite simple.  You can add or edit information.  However when attempting to add a record the not in list event fires but when it gets to DoCmd.RunCommand acCmdSaveRecord it goes back to the beginning and starts again nothing happens.  If you ans wer No then it will eventually exit the sub but only after error 3270 and error 2237 and then a box telling me the text isn't in the list.

```
Private Sub CboBrandCode_NotInList(NewData As String, Response As Integer)
On Error GoTo ErrorCrap
Dim ans As Variant

If NewData = "" Then
    Let ans = MsgBox("The Brand Code cannot be blank!", vbOKOnly)
    Exit Sub
End If

Let ans = MsgBox("Do you want to add the new Brand " & NewData & "?", vbYesNo)

If ans = vbYes Then
    DoCmd.RunCommand acCmdSaveRecord
    Response = acDataErrAdded
ElseIf ans = vbNo Then
    DoCmd.RunCommand acCmdUndo
    Response = acDataErrContinue
End If

Exit Sub

ErrorCrap:
    MsgBox "Error " & Err.Number & ": " & Error$

    Exit Sub

End Sub
```

Comment: Why do you have the `acCmdSaveRecord` in the "Yes" case? It shouldn't be necessary. And it is generally not a good idea to change bound data during a event that is raised by changes in bound data - it is easy to create circular events and errors.

Comment: It isn't necessary if I do not want to save the record.  This is a new record and saving the record is very desireable.  Your statement sounds as if you would never have any changes or additions to data.

Comment: Of course the record needs to be saved at some point. But the `NotInList` event happens if the user enters a value into a combobox that isn't in its rowsource. These are separate events and you should not try to link them automatically.

Comment: Why did you put Response variable as parameter? But you set this variable when vbYes/vbNo. Maybe you want a Function not a Sub, right?

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried substitute `Exit Sub` for `End`?

Maybe the problem is because when the program reaches `Exit Sub` in your  `Sub CboBrandCode_NotInList`, it goes back to a previous Sub or Function and restart again the code, but the parameters `NewData` or `Response` are now Empty or Null.

Do you call this Sub expecting a result from it?, if so, change the name `Sub CboBrandCode_NotInList` for `Function CboBrandCode_NotInList`